# Need to hyperlink my personal data to a shapefile

Tags: qgis

I want to hyperlink my personal data like Excel file to a shapefile. Can I do it in QGIS?

Comment: Are you sure you want to hyperlink not "join" the data using a common attribute?

Comment: Welcome to GIS.stackexchange. Please be more specific as to what you are trying to achieve. So far it is not clear.

Answer (score 2):

I'm an ESRI user, and I don't use QGIS (yet), but I found a tutorial on conducting a [TABLE JOIN](http://maps.cga.harvard.edu/qgis/wkshop/join_csv.php) with a quick Google search.  Your question is a little unclear, but it sounds very much like you're looking to join external data to your existing spatial database. If not, please clarify your question a little and I'm sure someone on this site will be able to assist you.  Also, I see that you're new, so welcome to GIS SE.

Take care & hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can see this, hope it could help:

[How to add links to PDFs in a Shapefile?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29464/how-to-add-links-to-pdfs-in-a-shapefile/29614#29614)