# How to add links to PDFs in a Shapefile?

Tags: qgis

I want an attribute in a shapefile named "Link" to add.

The works are all fine but then I would like to add a link in my directory.

This link accesses a PDF. Now, this PDF is not shown.

Is there any other solution or there is nothing to be done?

Comment: Where is the target of the link? On a network or on a local file system?  How will the link be used, by clicking once on inspection, or is it simply a record which will be used in another system?   There are a lot of case specific issues to this question which are outside of gis/QGIS.

Comment: The target of the link is stored on a local server. The connection is to simply display the PDF later.

Answer (score 9):

Three possibilities tested on Windws XP:

- create a new action of Type "Generic", action:
  cmd /c [% "url" %]
  where path is a field containg the full pathname: D:\Download\test.pdf
- create a new action of Type "Windows", action:
  "C:\Programme\Adobe\Reader 9.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe" "[% "path" %]"
  where path is a field containg the full pathname: D:\Download\test.pdf
- install apache for your local PC, point localhost to the root of D:\
  In Qgis, action of type "Open", action:
  http://[% "url" %]
  where url is a field with the path in format localhost/download/test.pdf

Some programming languages allow files to be accessed by file://D:/, but this does not work here.

Comment: how to open file location in network  \\fileserver\filefolder\file1.xls I tried all but couldn't.

Comment: See my answer on http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32961/adding-hotlink-in-qgis/32983#32983

Answer (score 1):

From the answer of Andre Joost, I found this video, hope it could help:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qXbtat3AsBs

Added: another video
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CUxkddOP3BQ&feature=related