# Adding a hotlink to an attribute field in QGIS

Tags: qgis

How to add hotlink to QGIS? I saw [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29464/how-to-add-links-to-pdfs-in-a-shapefile) but had some problem. I want to open network location like **\\fileserver\filefolder\file1.excel** but it ends with error.

Edit:
    The network location is stored in a column of the table eg. URL column contains **URL** value for each attribute. Different row has different URL.

Comment: It would help if you could describe the error.

Comment: @sgrieve Unable to run command. I actually have stored the location in one of the column and I have used it has an expression.

Comment: Maybe you need to prefix it with file:// or local://, since it is not directly on one of your disks. I imagine dos batch commands will have trouble interpreting that though.

Comment: @lynxlynxlynx still same error :(

Comment: On what OS are you using QGIS?

Comment: I am using windows @GiovanniManghi

Comment: Then the path to your program executable must be between '"'.

Comment: @GiovanniManghi can you give me example I am having problem still..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This way it works for me on Windows and Qgis 1.8.0:

Create a point shapefile with a field `url` of type string. Add a point and fill the url field with

```
\\<host>\<path>\<file>.xls
```

without any blanks or quotation marks unless you have blanks in folder and filenames. Don't forget to save the layer, end leave edit mode.

In the layers properties, create a new action of type `Generic` , name it `open` and add

```
cmd /c [% "url" %]
```

as action.

Select the `Action` icon, move the mouse over the point and click to open the excel sheet.
The Excel sheet should have the standard .xls extension.

Comment: tried it but my path has space i.e. my file name has space "test test12.xls" it opens a command window and nothing happens

Comment: It might work if you put the whole path inside quotes.  Just guessing though.

Comment: Just tested: "\\fileserver\filefolder\file 1.xls" (with the quotation marks!) in the shapefile field works.

Comment: Glad I could help.  Please vote my comment up if you think it was useful.

Comment: @Rayner its helpful but my url is one of the column of table

Comment: I'm not quiet sure what you mean: Path-to-file has to be build of column(field) name and content of the field? That could be done in some way by field calculator. Can you add a screenshot of the table?

Comment: At last the solution : cmd /c  "[% "URL_TSSR" %]". Using generic type action. See "" outside too.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use python. After reading a blog post from Tim Sutton at linfiniti [1] I learned you can use python in actions:

eg something along those lines:

```
from pywin32.client import Dispatch
xl = Dispatch('Excel.Application')
wb = xl.Workbooks.Open('C:\\Documents and Settings\\GradeBook.xls')
```

taken from another post [2]

[1] http://linfiniti.com/2012/03/a-python-layer-action-to-open-a-wikipedia-page-in-qgis/

[2] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247724/how-can-i-launch-an-instance-of-an-application-using-python

Comment: I don't know if it is excel or pdf as I have mentioned in the question it can be pdf or any other file too. I use it with mapinfo currently. It's easy in Mapinfo but I am not able to find this feature in Qgis easy.