# Issues with hotlinking in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I want to create hotlinks to open excel and image files but am having issues.

I fixed the issue with opening excel files by adding ""

```
cmd /c start excel.exe /r  "[% "Excel" %]"
```

However I can't get images to open??? rather than opening a specific program can qgis just open a file with the default system viewer?

```
cmd /c start rundll32 "C:\Program Files\Windows Photo Viewer\PhotoViewer.dll" "[% "Location" %]"
```

I tried a few option with rundll32.exe C:\WINDOWS\System32\shimgvw.dll,ImageView_Fullscreen %1 but they don't work.

Also tried [image] as per Answer from Nathan but I get "Unable to run command"

=== Original post follows.

I have looked at [Adding a hotlink to an attribute field in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32961/adding-a-hotlink-to-an-attribute-field-in-) and http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Actions-HowTo-td4534256.html . The code from here launches excel but can't find the file...

I have the following in the properties-actions
[image]

when I try to open it I get
[image]
It looks like the issue is with the spaces in the directory name...

P:\2013\361_xxx_Production\Input\Supply1\28-05-xxx_Application_Packages\Roads photos and form 2s\Roads Package 4\Form 2 Output xxx Roads Package 4.xls

it seems to be getting truncated at the first space in the directory. It is bad datastructure but I can't change this. Is there any way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try wrapping the expression in quotes:

```
cmd /c start excel.exe /r "[% "Excel" %]"
```

You can just use the Open action type

[image]

Comment: thanks. I found that aand was just updating the question when you answered... I still have an issue with images though.

Comment: Answer coming for that

Comment: Did you change you `Type` to Open like in my image. Not the name.  I see yours has `Generic`