# Displaying images in QGIS - Actions - unable to run command

Tags: qgis, image

I was following the video below:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aW7CI7SiqQ4&ab_channel=WanjohiKibui

In order to prepare the action in my QGIS project. I want to have my images popped-up instantly.

Unfortunately, I am getting an error like this:

[image]

My action properties look as follows:

[image]

The image directory is related to the project path.

I also tried the command:

```
   eog [%Image%]
```

and

```
   display [%Image%]
```

as per the thread here:

[Using Hyperlink URL in attribute table of QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/217390/using-hyperlink-url-in-attribute-table-of-qgis)

the result the same everywhere

What causes the problem? Is there something with the hotlink?

[Issues with hotlinking in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/63382/issues-with-hotlinking-in-qgis)

Comment: in your second screengrab your action type is "Unix" you need to change that to "open", see @Leehan for more detail

Comment: not working, no error and no reaction. I guess that 3.12 version has some bug

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I did in QGis 3.16 with Windows.
I create a field `img`in the attribute table, containing a path like `C:\blaba\myphoto.jpg`.
Then in the layer properties and `action` menu :

[image: action menu]

Then use the wheel in tools bar as usual :

[image]

Comment: not wirking. I guess, that maybe it's some bug somewhere. I have 3.12 version.

Comment: any error message ? are you sure about urls of pictures ? You use Windows ?

Comment: Yes, Windows 10. What I do not understand from your post are layer properties. What should we change in the layer properties.

Comment: In layer properties, you have a menu named `action`. You have to create an action with the same parameter as shown in the first image of my answer, and choose at the bottom the field containing path to the pictures `[%Image%]`in your case.    Don't write anything before.

Answer (score 0):

Your command line is right display[%image%]. The Type I used is Open even my system is Windows 10.The image pops when I click using Identify Features tool.

Comment: Your image doesnt show