# Export SQL table with images to Qgis

Tags: qgis, database, mysql, image

In MySQL Workbench 6.3 CE I created a table with some columns.
One of this columns is of data type 'BLOB' to insert an image.

Now i am looking for a way to export this table and import this table afterwards in Qgis to create a map of it.

If i am exporting the table to a 'CSV' file i lost my images...

Comment: I can't see a blob type for attributes in QGIS. Why don't you use a string attribute storing an url ([see here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32961/adding-a-hotlink-to-an-attribute-field-in-qgis))?