# Create a hyperlink to a pdf file in the attribute table

Tags: qgis, hyperlink

I want to add a hyperlink to a pdf file into the attribute table of a vector layer. I already read the documentation about evis and the answered questions about this here. It didn't seem difficult, but I still can't create a hyperlink...can someone give me a short step by step information about this? Unfortunately I have no access to youtube...

I'm using Qgis (2.0.1) and evis is a plugin that should allow to create such hyperlinks via a event browser. I first added a column "Link" to the attribute table and put the link to the document in this column. 
this is the link to the documentation for evis: http://www.qgis.org/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_evis.html#figure-evis-2

Thanks a lot!
G.H.

Comment: Can you edit the GIS software and version that you are using to create this PDF into your Question, and at the same time correct/explain what you mean by "evis", please?  If you list the precise steps that you have tried, you are likely to get a quicker Answer.

Comment: Have you seen this Q and A : http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29464/how-to-add-links-to-pdfs-in-a-shapefile ?

Answer (score 4):

You do not need to use *evis* plugin. The **actions menu** will allow you to open a link stored as attribute value.
Please see the following section of QGIS documentation : http://www.qgis.org/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#actions-menu

On the "Layer properties" > click *Action*.

**Method A :**

Then enter the type of the action ( I choose *Unix*), give the action a name and specifiy the command to open the file. I get something link :

```
/usr/bin/acroread  [% "LINK" %]
```

where LINK is the dynamic value you already have.

**Method B :**

Even more simple (available in QGIS 2.2 - not sure for v2.0.1) :

**Choose type of action "open", then enter `[% "LINK" %]` in *action* field.**

*This method B was tested with success. See screenshot below :*

[image: QGIS screenshot]

**Edit : After settings actions, you will be able to open the link by selecting the *Info tool* and click the desired object. Clicking the "Open File" text into the pop-up window will open the file.**

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried both methods and read the documentation and the result is similar: I now have a link in my attribute table but it's not a hyperlink.

Comment: Please see my edit + screenshot in first post

Comment: I'm sorry, I did everything as you explained, but I still can't klick on the link. I also don't have this little sign like you in front of "Ouvrir fichier".

Comment: Are you sure, you have selected the desired layer is selected? Be sure your action is defined as follow : http://i.imgur.com/yjFNaoi.png

Comment: Yes I did this and I tried it again, but it still doesn't work. My action looks similar to yours but I have "capture" is checked (I can't deselect it).

Comment: This should not be a problem. Could you post some screenshots?

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/xhNdl.png

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/28QlM.png

Comment: I'm not familiar with Windows UI but I'm not sure you are using the right tool to query the spatial entity. Use the _Info tool_. Look at the screenshot : http://i.stack.imgur.com/b6NQy.png

Comment: I'm sure I used this tool. http://i.stack.imgur.com/pasYV.jpg

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the whole application?

Comment: What do you mean? The whole map window? Or the action-window?

Comment: I think I understood. It seems, your _Info tool_ displays automatically the attributes form - and you should look for an explanation - maybe becaus you use evis or some specific settings. For my part, when I click it, I get first the pop-up you've already seen, then only clicking on "display forms", I get the form pop-up : http://i.imgur.com/ctstf4n.png. Try to query another layer to see what's happening, maybe on another project.

Comment: I finally made it :) I don't know why it didn't work in the first project, but in the other one..and it's strange that the pop-up window appears only if I click on the border where two polygons come together but never when I click in the middle of a polygon...I will check my settings. But anyway, thank you very much for your help!