# How to create a hyperlink in one point?

Tags: qgis, hyperlink

I started to use Quantum GIS 2.0.1 Dufour and I'm still trying to understand how to work with it. I have a shape layer in QGIS made of points, and I want to attach a different hyperlink to each of the points. Is that possible? For now, I have only accomplished attaching several hyperlinks, but to the entire shape layer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a column in your attribute table called "Link" and add the link you like to each point. In the properties menu, you can create a action. Select "Open" as type and give it a name. Klick on add attribute and add the action to the list. You can open the link by klicking on the points with the info-arrow. 
See also this: [Create a hyperlink to a pdf file in the attribute table](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/88593/create-a-hyperlink-to-a-pdf-file-in-the-attribute-table)

Comment: More info about actions in the [users manual](http://www.qgis.org/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#actions-menu).

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand how can I add the hyperlink in the attribute table. When I add a colum, I can only choose 4 types, but none for hyperlink. I know how to do it by clicking in the properties menu and adding an action. But that way I can't especifie a link to a especific point, can I?

Comment: You choose string as type and add the new column. Then you can add the hyperlink manually for each point.