# How can i create a link to a whole folder?

Tags: qgis, pdf

I know how to create a hyperlink to a single pdf-file: [Create a hyperlink to a pdf file in the attribute table](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/88593/create-a-hyperlink-to-a-pdf-file-in-the-attribute-table)

But now I want to make a link to a folder with 3 or 4 pdf files in it. Is that possible? 
I tried it the same way as linking a pdf but it didn't work.

I'm working ith qgis 2.0.1.

Comment: What operating system? Still on Linux? What's the desktop environment or file manager you're using?

Comment: And can you update your question to show exactly what you tried so far please?

Comment: No, windows. I exactly did what I would do to create a link for a single pdf: I filled the link to the fodler into a new column ("Path") and I created a action called "open folder", type "open" with the "Path"-attribute as reference.

Comment: What does your hyperlink look like at present?

Comment: Something like: H:\04_environment\04_02 subjects

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to my question myself: It didn't work, because "H" was not enough to create a link to the folder, I had to use the whole remote connection link for the folder "H".

Comment: what did you mean with "remote connection link"?
I'm trying to do the same: use the actions to open a folder (not just a PDF). How did you manage that?

Answer (score 0):

Generally you can create a hyperlink to a folder on a web server by omitting a file from the path.

So for example this is a link to the folder that contains GML schema:

http://schemas.opengis.net/gml/

However, this isn't always possible because many web server administrators don't want users to root around in the file structure, so they either disable folder/directory browsing, in which case that you get an error ([HTTP 403](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)) when you omit a file name, or they add a default document (for example [example of default web page](https://gis.stackexchange.com/)).

Comment: I think, I used the correct path. But if I want to open the folder, nothing happens, there's no error message or default document.